# Whether to use friedman test to test differences in categories across four topics?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, categorical-data

I have collected data where respondents provide on of the following responses

```
1. non interested to be involved
2. only get information on the topic but not participating
3. consulting on the topic
4. taking responsibility
```

for each each of the following four topics

```
1. setting priorities
2. raising revenues
3. distributing funds 
4. monitoring
```

I would like to test if the topic influences the preferred way for participation.

**Can you use Friedman's test to examine whether responses differ across topics?**

Comment: You say there are 5 ways to be involved but only list 4.

Comment: @Glen_b In fact there were 5 options in the questionaire but I have combined for my analysis two of them in one -responsibility. These were taking part as a partner which means shared responsibility and dominating role which means taking complete responsibility for the desicions on the topic. So, you can consider them as four at the end. The reason to comine was that the there were very low frequences on the domination role like 2 or 3 people and the other reason was that combinig the last two options in one responsibilty gives me the chanse to comapre my results with other study.